# PHP / MySQL : Searching Fulltext using MATCH() AGAINST() & ORDER BY?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-indexing

Please could somebody help me to complete my mission to search a database (that have 2 fulltext index columns) using multi-words and order by price DESC.

This query does work (searches for the keywords entered by the user, create a score based on how many words been matched) but the ORDER BY price DESC seems to be a little strange. Example

`SELECT *, MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('nissan ford astra golf' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM listings WHERE MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('nissan ford astra golf' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY price DESC;`

```
Ford Escort | Used | £100 
Vauxhall Astra | New | £2000 
VW Golf | Used | £500 
Nissan Micra | Used | £2000
```

I would like to set the price column as the priority to ORDER BY DESC or ASC.

This has taken nearly 5 years to 
get this far so hopefully some knowledgable fellow can help me complete this misson.

Many Thanks in Advance. 
Andrew.

Comment: It looks like your `order by` is not even being executed.  Whatever the keys, the two values of `£2000` should be next to each other.  Could the prices be stored as strings with leading spaces in some cases?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect price appears to be stored as a string rather than a number.  Here is one work-around, assuming you have no decimals points:

```
order by length(price) desc, price desc
```

Alternatively, converting to a number:

```
order by substr(price, 2) + 0
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I have spent best part of 5 years trying to get a search to work, left loads of questions on various websites and you told me in 10mins... Your a diamond... I cannot explain how greatful I am. Many many thanks...